# Bash script: Create a New User, then Delete the Existing User

Tags: bash, users

I am  trying to write a script, to create a new user, then delete the existing user. The script does not show any errors or warnings, but the existing user is not getting deleted, when running from the bash. Strange that, everything is fine if each command is run (one by one) in the terminal.

The code I am using is:

```
read NEW_USER

sudo adduser -gecos "" $NEW_USER
sudo usermod -aG sudo $NEW_USER
    
su - $NEW_USER
sudo killall -u EXISTING_USER
sudo deluser --remove-home EXISTING_USER
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Are you running the script as `EXISTING_USER`? if so, it will be killed before it reaches the `deluser` command

Comment: NEVER put sudo in a script.  edit: I would start with an echo of EXISTING_USER

Comment: @steeldriver. So far the script was run from another user (third user), because I was testing the code.

Comment: @Rinzwind. Noted. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Rinzwind — What is your justification for never using `sudo` in a Bash script, please?

Comment: Ashok, please always quote variables in your script, so `"$NEW_USER"`. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches down the line.

Comment: @PaddyLandau how long do you have? :-) 1st off: it is ugly coding. starting the script with sudo does the same job. 2nd: security wise I would put this kind of script in `/root/bin/`, have only permissions on the "user" (aka 700), and owner+group root. And should be executed after doing `sudo -i`.

Comment: I don't know very much about scripts, but is it possible that it's not working because you didn't begin with the shebang `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @BenM, the shebang was given in the actual code.

Comment: @Rinzwind — Thanks. I'm not sure that I agree, precisely for security, but this discussion is outside the scope of this AskUbuntu. I don't know if we can continue the discussion elsewhere?

Comment: you can know the current user with `whoami` such as `CURRENTUSER=$(whoami)`. I would logout then do ctrl-F4 for a new terminal then login as root then `killall -HUP -u OLDUSER`